# Waiting the end of a REPORT task without having Administrator permissions

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I am developing a plugin for SonarQube 6.3.1 which execute an analysis and then generate a docx report.

The problem is that I have to wait between these both actions that SonarQube finishes its REPORT task. My plugin is destined to lambda users so without Administrator permissions: so I can not use activityStatus service.

Is there an other way to know if the reporting of a project in SonarQube is terminated? (inside a plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis take place on the server side ? I think you should run it on a client side, not server side.
Write a plugin with  @BatchSide  and implements org.sonar.api.batch.postjob.PostJob.
Then your method will execute soon analysis is finish (as you requested)
See https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/hooks/DisplayIssuesInScanner.java

And by the way with PostJobContext  object you have all infos you need to fill a custom report

Comment: But using @ScannerSide (@BatchSide is deprecated in version 6.3.1) I can not know  when SonarQube has finished to import data from scanners. My aim is to have a reporter which can be used from every client not only from the client which ran the analysis.

Comment: look at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/hooks/DisplayQualityGateStatus.java it is exactly you want